# When should unsound, private functions be marked unsafe?

Tags: rust, unsafe

[The Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/working-with-unsafe.html) gives the following example for an unsound, but not unsafe function in the context of a hypothetical `Vec` implementaiton:

```rust
fn make_room(&mut self) {
    // grow the capacity
    self.cap += 1;
}
```

This function is purposly not marked `unsafe`, despite being able to break the internal assumptions of Vec, because it is not `pub`, so the public API remains sound despite it's existance.

---

With this line of reasoning you could argue that no private function should ever have to be `unsafe`, because in the end they can't really be worse than this one. (Allows safe code in the same module to produce segfault).

So, **when should you mark an unsound, private function as unsafe ?**.

As I don't want this to become opinion based,
are there any good resources talking about guidelines for this, or could you give some
anecdotal evidence from larger projects?

Comment: Seems kind of subjective. It really depends on the team you're working with and how much protecting they need from being able to do things that lead to broken outcomes.

Comment: *"when should you mark an unsound, private function as unsafe?"* - my answer: Always, doesn't matter if its private since it can be used to clearly indicate unsoundness to a co-developer who *can* use the private function. I don't believe the Nomicon *recommends* this, but only shows it as a technical demonstration where the boundary of "soundness" lies.

Comment: The fact the first two comments already disagree makes me glad I asked. I'm not sure If I fully agree with the *always stance*, as it feels weird that factoring out a regular piece of code into a private function somehow makes it unsafe.

Comment: I voted to close as opinion-based, but I believe this is an important question, so I will answer with my opinion here despite me tending to not answer closure-candidate questions in comments. And my opinion is, _it depends_. Unsound APIs should _never_ be exposed across crates: that's a rule. But you should strive to make it as self-contained as possible. If it is possible to make a single module encapsulating all `unsafe`, great; and even inside the module, I usually mark functions as `unsafe` if it does not cause too much disturbance and the function can be used to violate invariants.

Comment: I always recommend programming with invariants when writting unsafe code: document the invariants of each field and struct, and document every piece of code changing them with an `// INVARIANT:` comment (similar to `// SAFETY:` comments) documenting how they keeps the invariants. Then, you can mark any function, even private, that breaks the invariants as unsafe, and includes what is necessary to use it safely in its safety preconditions.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman:  I would ask for some time before we consider closing this as opinion based, because I think that there could be a good, non opinion based answer here. It would be a shame if that never happened because this got nuked prematurely. That's why I specifically asked for sources, not for opinions.

Comment: The problem is that I don't believe an official recommendation exist.

Comment: Quote from the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html): *"It is the programmer's responsibility when writing `unsafe` code to ensure that any safe code interacting with the `unsafe` code cannot trigger these behaviors."*
I'd argue that this also counts for internal functions. Don't just think about user safety - think about collaborating with other programmers on your own code base. The Rust safety invariants are for fearless coding, which isn't given any more if you need to think about soundness issues in safe code.

Comment: On the other hand, it is true that some times (like in your example) it is required to have multiple safe functions that might have to trust each other. I agree with Chayim here - ideally one encapsulates all the `unsafe` code in a small module. If that's not possible, it's important to document it properly to prevent the next unknowing library maintainer from messing up invariants. The only hard rule is that the **user** of a library may never be able to trigger undefined behavior through safe functions.

Comment: In the end I do agree that there is no way to answer this question without getting opinion based - there is no rule how to write internal functions. `unsafe` and soundness is a concept that applies only to public functionality of structs. But `unsafe` on private functions can indeed be a good way to communicate soundness issues to other programmers of your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: **Mark **every** unsound function `unsafe`, unless you have a very good reason not to.**

---

As pointed out by @Finomis, quoting from the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> It is the programmer's responsibility when writing unsafe code to ensure that any safe code interacting with the unsafe code cannot trigger these behaviors."

The following are some concrete patterns and examples where private, unsound functions that are not marked `unsafe` are used and why.

---

#### 1. The `unsafe` Core Pattern

Some crates, especially ones implementing data structures, have to carry lots of assumptions
about the state of their data. Marking every private function that makes use of these assumptions as `unsafe` prevents the detection of unsafe patterns like pointer dereferences or unsafe calls, as everything is already unsafe.

A pattern to get around this issue is to isolate the
functions with these assumptions into a separate crate/module with accompanying `// SAFETY` comments,
were it is understood that private functions have to take care to uphold them,
even if they aren't marked unsafe. This can sometimes even allow you to enable `#![deny(unsafe_code)]` for the rest of the codebase.

An example of this pattern can be seen in the [IndexHashMap](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap/blob/master/src/map/core/raw.rs) crate.

#### 2. Implementing Traits

When implementing a foreign trait for a **private type**,
(e.g. implementing `std::hash::Hash` so the type can be used with `std::HashMap`), the function *cannot* be marked `unsafe`, because the trait API requires it not to be. An unsound implementation can still be fine though,
if special care is taken to make sure the private type is always in a valid state. (If anybody has a good example for this, please reply with a comment).

#### 3. Macros

While macros aren't technically functions, they are often used in similar ways.
Somewhat surprisingly, macros *cannot* be marked `unsafe`. The general consensus [seems to be](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/do-we-need-unsafe-macros/12156) that macros will always have to be checked carefully, so there's no need for the unsafe keyword. So the `!` in the call kind of means `unsafe`. Still, usecases for private unsound macros exist, meaning that **their callsites** will not be found by a simple grep for `unsafe`.

One example of this can be found in in [encoding_rs](https://github.com/hsivonen/encoding_rs/blob/a962ef4f8e569ccf5a22104d19cc10e8a0b458e6/src/simd_funcs.rs#L217),
were the macro contains a `return` (so it cannot be a function) based on an unsafe conditional. This is admittedly a bad example, as in this case
the macro contains an `unsafe` block, so it could have been *essentially* turned into
an `unsafe` macro by **leaving out that unsafe block in the macro**, so **the caller** has to place the macro in an unsafe block to make it compile. But this trick would not be possible if the macro was purely unsound (without requiring unsafe).

---

##### Additional Points

- This might seem obvious, but: A function does not become `unsafe` through it's callers. If a (private) function `foo` outputs bytes, and another function `bar` unsafely calls `std::str::from_utf8_unchecked` on the output of `foo`,
  that is generally no reason to mark `foo` as `unsafe`, despite the fact that changing `foo` could now cause UB. A mechanism to better express these kinds of caller assumptions is `unsafe trait`.
- All `extern` functions are implicitly `unsafe`. It might seem like one usecase where this would come up are binding for other languages, but here rust elects to be a bit overprotective, forcing you to write a safe wrapper around your highly dangerous `extern "C" { fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32}`.
  What does happen in practice though, is that a bit of binding glue code will be written in C/C++ itself, which is arguably no better than an *unsafe core*,
  because all code in those languages is inherently unsafe.
- Function pointers are no valid reason to do this. It might seem like there's a case for it if you want an API like `sort_by_key` to take a function that's inherently unsafe, but it's always possible to correctly mark that function as unsafe and give a lambda like `|x| unsafe {my_actual_fn(x)}` to the API instead.
- Rust has unfortunately made the decision that the a function marked `unsafe` (meaning it's API is not safe an can be misused) implicitly has an `unsafe` **body** (meaning that some safety restrictions on the implementation are lifted), without requiring any `unsafe` blocks. Fortunately, [steps are being taken to rectify this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71668).
  This change could reduce the need for the *unsafe core* pattern.

Comment: I'm don't consider myself an expert in this topic, but I tried my best to aggregate what I found. Somebody with more expertise would surely have been able to give better examples or explore the topic more thoroughly. That is what I hoped for when raising this question. I partially answered this myself to prove that it is possible to give an unbiased, helpful answer even to questions where there is no cookie-cut binary answer, which is why I consider it **wrong** to close this as oppinion based. As this proves, 'it can be answered with facts and citations '